# QVector<int>[index] returning another QVector?

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I'm kind of new to C++ programming, so I'm probably just missing something, but I've been trying to figure this out for almost an hour now.

I have a set of `QLabels` in my `UI` that I want to update around twice a second. The data it gets updated with is stored in a `QVector<int>` of size 12.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    [...]
    knobCoords(new QVector<int>(12)),
    updateTimer(new QTimer(this))
{
    connect(updateTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateCoordLabels()));
    updateTimer->start(500);
}
```

In order to update the labels, I need to convert my `int` values to strings. This is done directly in the `updateCoordLabels()` function:

```
void MainWindow::updateCoordLabels() {
    tracker->updateCoordData(*knobCoords);
    ui->knobA_xCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords[0]));
    ui->knobA_yCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords[1]));
    ui->knobA_zCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords[2]));
    ui->knobB_xCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords[3]));
    [...]
    updateTimer->start(500);
}
```

However, when I compile the program, I get a type mismatch. For some reason, `knobCoords[index]` doesn't return an `int` as expected, but a `QVector<int>` instead.

```
mainwindow.cpp:124: error: C2665: 'std::to_string': none of the 9 overloads could convert all the argument types
[...]
mainwindow.cpp:124: while trying to match the argument list '(QVector<int>)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: all these `new`'s scare me

Comment: `knobCoords(new QVector<int>(12))`  suggests that `knobCoords` is a `QVector*` (a pointer, not a "plain" `QVector`)

Comment: It seems that `knobCoords` is a pointer. You need to dereference it first.

Comment: It's only 2 and they get destroyed together with the mainwindow. :)

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. What is `knobCoords`? Is it `QVector<int>*`? If that is the case, why are you dynamically allocating it (with `new`)? And in addition to that `knobCoords[0]` is trying to reference `knobCoords` as an array (containing `QVector<int>` elements). If you intended to call `operator[]` of a `QVector`, you need to do it explicitly (`->operator[](0)`), or dereference it first: `(*knobCoords)[0]`.

Comment: I think your error do not have to do with the `int` but the `std::string`. The `std::to_string` error means that you have to ste the text of `ui->knobA_xCoordsLabel` and the rest using a `QString`, not an `std::string`. Try using [`QString::number`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number)

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved it now. I switched it so knobCoords is not a pointer anymore and used QString::number() instead of to_string (as a QLabel takes a QString anyways).

Comment: Nice that you solved it. Honestly you should also try to allocate your `QVector` on the stack, not on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

`knobCoords` is a `QVector<int>*` meaning you must deference `knobCoords` before using the subscript operator on it.

You could instead do:

```
ui->knobA_xCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords->at(0)));
ui->knobA_yCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords->at(1)));
ui->knobA_zCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords->at(2)));
ui->knobB_xCoordsLabel->setText(to_string(knobCoords->at(3)));
```

---

A few cautionary notes:

1. Don't use pointers unnecessarily. Aside from the confusion you've just seen them to introduce, if they aren't handled correctly in the object destructor they lead to memory leakage. A more significant problem as error recovery comes into play
2. Separate your business logic from your front end. A good step to take toward that is never using Qt containers internally. Qt does a great job of playing nice with standard containers, so rather than a `QVector<int>` prefer `vector<int>` or if you are using a fixes size: `array<int, 12>`
3. [Although it doesn't make any difference for `QVector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#at) for standard containers you'll want to avoid using the `at` function preferring the subscript operator as `at` incurs a bounds checking expense even in release

Comment: The bounds checking may be an advantage, especially for beginners. I would recommend to use it except when there's a real bottleneck in that code.

Comment: @Murphy To each his own, I'm simply trying to highlight that while there is no difference for Qt containers there is for standard containers.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this and similar issues, get rid of the pointers wherever possible, allocate variables on the stack.

This is C++, [not Java](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#new-java). You're bound to get a lot of memory leaks this way, as there's no garbage collector. And it will save you from lots of headaches like the above.